# How to Create Common Logins for Different PHP applications?

Tags: php, web-applications, web, login-control

I want to create a common logins for my php applications. My website has four and more php applications. I want to create a common login for these php applications in the same way as google uses common login for its apps. My website is new and has not be indexed much. Can I create a common login for users to use my website apps. Is it simpler and possible.

My website :http://goo.gl/d2n20q

Comment: Are these have same domain name?

Answer (score 1):

You can. It's called [Single Sing-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Sign-On) (SSO), there should be *A LOT* information about how to implement it on the web. Here's one on PHP that you could use and customize: http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/

If it's cookie based auth (you authenticate the user, then save a cookie with the user auth info), you will need to take the domain into consideration, that is all web apps should have the same domain i.e. www.finysel.com, app1.finysel.com, otherapp.finysel.com (and set the cookie accordingly).

An easy approach is just create a database/table for logins, then share common files for auth thru your PHP sites `include /Path/to/shared/Login/login.php`.

You can also create a web service that takes the login information and returns if the auth is valid and the auth info required. An easy way is just to implement it with JSON responses (if the user and pass are valid, then you return the User in JSON, if the user is undefined then it didn't authenticated successfully), then you can create just one Ajaxy Login that you can re-use in all your websites.

Note that SSO just Authenticates the user. To check for privileges and permissions you would need to add Authorisation layer.

Finally, PHP has an [oAuth](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.oauth.php) module that you could use if you decide to implement a full fledged service. You can become your own oAuth provider. That's how you'd go if you want an implementation like the one provided by "Sign with your Google/Facebook/Twitter/OpenID Account" but might be overkill for what you need.

Comment: Such a detailed answer I think I need to find a project where I could put it into action ;)

Comment: I want users to sign-in with google, twitter or facebook and then want to use same logins on all web apps I provide with my website. 
So will just one sign-in with social network passes same info on all apps. I mean my web apps are made from open sources services
 like my forum is an app from vanilla forums and my blog from wordpress, my shop is opencart and my classifieds is from osclass

Comment: I need one login in main page like www.example.com and then same logins to be used in shops,classified,blogs and forums. 
So will these service can integrate with the user info passed by the login app or will they take info and create user database like they are doing now.? 
And I don't use sub domain like app1.example.com or app2.example.com instead I have www.example.com/app1 , www.example.com/app2 etc please also tell, 
which is better to create common login ?

Comment: Application wise it's the same to have app1.domain.com than domain.com/app1 but Search Engines might prefer one over the other. If you want to auth against Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc. Look into oAuth2. Check out http://thephpleague.com/ they have packages for both server (You authenticating users) and client (Using Google, Twitter, etc.) authentication. And you will still need your local User database, the services just will return the info that the user's auth'd you won't have passwords, but will have ID's and User Info.

Answer (score 0):

create a database dedicated to users, and authenticate users against this database on all apps.